# Tensorflow LSTM - Simple model returns only zeros forever

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I build a very simple model to predict harmony for given melody. Melody is represented as one-hot vector, harmony as k-hot vector (sparse vector with up to 5 ones). One batch of harmony/melody has shape `(batch_size, 64, 48)`.

Unfortunatelly, after few iterations (~100), this model starts to predict zeros everywhere (`prediction` tensor is full of zeros) and stays here forever. Loss decrease up to some point and it seems it just stuck here (probably because my output is full of zeros).

After manually checking some records, dataset seems to be fine. My dataset contains ~10k records.

Here is my model:

```
import itertools
import tensorflow as tf
from dataset import get_batch

timesteps = 64
melody_dim = 48
harmony_dim = 48

batch_size = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
melody_batch, harmony_batch = get_batch(['./dataset.tfrecords'], batch_size=batch_size)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(128)
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, melody_batch, dtype=tf.float32)
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(output, harmony_dim, activation_fn=None)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=harmony_batch, logits=logits))
solver = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

prediction = tf.greater(logits, 0)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in itertools.count():
        _, curr_loss = sess.run([solver, loss], {
            batch_size: 32
        })

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Anybody know where the problem could be? Should I use embedding or something similar? I suspect that the problem is because my label (harmony) vector is very sparse.

Comment: Your problem seems to be multilabel (more than one right class per sample). Therefore sigmoid ist the right choice as activation function. But as loss binary crossentropy should work better. Also how even ist the occurence of each class? Have you considered using class weights?

Comment: Occurrence of each class should be more or less same (each music sample is transposed). I thought that `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` is binary cross entropy. So should I just calculate sum of log of logit (without sigmoid) for each truth label?

Comment: No sigmoid is fine. Actually i made a mistake because your loss function already use the binary version of cross entropy which is the right one for multi label problems like yours.  As for other ideas: Sometimes very strong regularization can kill your weights and drop the output to zero. A good next step could be to monitor your weights with tensorboard.

Comment: When I last checked, weights of LSTM was after few iterations either very close to -1 or close to 1. By class weights you mean `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`?

Comment: Probably I‘m not familiar with the tf.nn syntay. I prefer tf.keras. I will check tomorrow. But it seems like every class is labeled right like every 10 ten samples. Class weights can improve your classifications but missing weights should not cause such behaviour. Besides that I‘m out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: I'll try it and eventually write a results. And thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems that `tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` help a little.